# Windows 2003 lost file extensions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, file-extension

I have a server with windows 2003, recently i installed a software in this server. When i restarted server my all files can't open sending to a command prompt saying: No program associated with ".exe" file extension. This occurred to all files types in system. When i go see file types association i see this: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WScript.exe "%1" %*, change result but when restart return to same.

Any idea to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I would instantly uninstall the software I installed befor...
Because a server with lost .exe association isn´t useful at all. If that fixes the problem I would google the Problem in reference to the software. maybe there is already a hotfix for this.